# In what configuration file format do regular expressions not need escaping?

Tags: configuration, file-formats

I want a configuration file for a .NET program.
This file is to configure pairs of regular expressions.
The regular expressions belong within a hierarchy of sections.

```
Section1
    SubsectionA
        regular expression
        regular expression
    SubsectionB
        regular expression
        regular expression
Section2
    (etc.)
```

Or in Markdown format

```
# Section1

## SubsectionA

    regular expression
    regular expression
```

Anyway I want a configuration file format in which the regular expression literals do not need to be escaped.

What configuration file format supports this? Even [YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301650/49942) requires escaping.

The two examples I showed above -- i.e. an indented text file, and Markdown -- are OK but non-standard.

Comment: “even YAML requires escaping” – usually, YAML values work just fine without quoting/escaping. The exception is if the value begins with one of the special YAML sequences such as a `key: ` or `- `, `{`, `[`, `!tag` markers. The linked question seems to be about a parser that doesn't conform to any version of the YAML specification.

Comment: @amon Thanks for clarifying that. But I have regular expressions which begin with `[`.

Comment: I see two votes-to-close because, "This question doesn’t meet a Software Engineering Stack Exchange guideline." -- please tell me which guideline it doesn't meet, in case I can fix that.

Comment: Both votes are for: "Questions asking for assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code, or using coding tools, are off-topic here. These can be asked on Stack Overflow if they include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and a Minimal, Reproducible Example of the problem." This could be seen as a tool recommendation question.  Those are considered off topic.

Comment: I think this is "design" question -- I'm not asking about source code at all, so I don't think it's on-topic on SO -- and I was asking about a file format, not about a software implementation to handle that format, so I don't see it as a "tool recommendation" question.

Comment: Will your regular expressions contain linebreaks?

Comment: @Bergi Is it even possible for a regular expression to contain a linebreak? If you want to specify a linebreak in a regular expression then I think you do that using `\n` or similar.

Comment: @ChrisW Yes, [it's used to make very complicated regular expressions more readable](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html). But if you don't need that, just use any config file format with newline delimiters.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7705385/49942) seems like a good .NET example of that. And no I was only looking to support single-line expressions.

Comment: A `properties` file has the format `«key»:«value»`, with each key-value pair on a separate line. If I remember correctly, that does not need escaping. Will that be sufficient?

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not how that implements hierarchical sections, where each section may contain several property values. And the last two lines of the example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties#Format suggest there's some escaping required, of backslashes.

Comment: You imply you don't want something "non-standard", but not said what kind of standard format you want - ISO-defined or something less rigorous?

Comment: @TobySpeight Something a programmer would recognize and accept, would like, as a sensible configuration file format for the purpose in a code review (see [this comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/432048?noredirect=1#comment949950_432082)). I'm leaning towards XML (with CDATA) because configuration files of other .NET applications of ours are XML; or CSV, because that's so easy to parse; or YAML because it's easier for the human to to read and write than CSV, and has an already-written parser library/package (although it is 3rd-party not .NET Core).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CDATA sections in XML should do.

Here's a stackoverflow post about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

I remember it took me a while to understand how to use them. A DOM parser has a dedicated instruction for creating a CDATA section but there is no equivalent statement for reading them. Reading is transparent, you just read the contents of the element that has the CDATA section in it to have the literal text returned.

Here's an example taken from the input data file of a code scrutinizer I once made. It allows the definition of the forms of problematic code fragments using regular expressions.

```
<IssueBuster type="Basic" name="Suspicious lambdas" skip="true">
    <Description>
        <!-- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465040/using-lambda-expressions-for-event-handlers -->
        A lambda expression is used for event handlers which inhibits unsubscribing.
    </Description>
    <Regex><![CDATA[\+\=\s*\([^\s\,]+\,\s*[^\s\)]+\)\s*=>]]></Regex>
    <SkipFileNames>
        <!-- If any of these inner texts appears in a file path, this buster will ignore that file. -->
        <FileName>SMMdataComponent\DeltaPlusGenerator\TestForm.cs</FileName>
        <FileName>Toolchain\Validate-TranslationEnums</FileName>
        <FileName>Tools\JcSimulator</FileName>
        <FileName>Tools\AR3toGps</FileName>
        <FileName>Tools\XMLConverter</FileName>
        <FileName>GitManipulator.cs</FileName>
    </SkipFileNames>
</IssueBuster>
```

Note that CDATA takes this form:

```
<![CDATA[your_literal_text]]>
```

Whatever you put in between the inner square brackets will be returned verbatim.

To wrap this up: in the unlikely event you have to include a ]]> sequence in the content, you can split the content after the second ] and create two consecutive CDATA sections. This can easily be implemented recursively.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how an XML file would look with CDATA sections? I guess that CDATA would only be used to allow the regular expressions to be written literally, while the section and subsection structure would be expressed using tags.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I added an example.

Comment: A CDATA section is a form of escaping, but doesn't require *additional* escaping in the middle of the regular expression.

Comment: How does a `CDATA` section handle the presence of `]]>` within the literal text?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Please follow the link in my post to the SO question and find your answer.

Comment: "...In CDATA you cannot include the string `]]>`..." There are possibilities to use `]]>` but as far as i see it must be escaped. So storing a regex in CDATA whose end is `]]>` may be a little bit tricky.

Answer (score 13):

This is indeed an interesting question, as commonly the requirements for config file formats are somewhat different, so it's understandable that available formats don't really support this requirement.

If there are no other configuration data in those files, having a non-standard but easily readable and editable format is ok (of course that's just my humble opinion, there's no absolute truth here.)

CDATA sections in XML as mentioned by Martin Maat are standard, but probably a little cumbersome and error-prone when editing. You also need to think up a proper XML schema for the XML tags, as just using `<Section1>` and `<Section2>` would be counter to XML conventions when `Section1` and `Section2` actually have the same structure. `<section name="1">...</section>` would be more appropriate but tedious to type.

YAML with the pipe format might actually work and is probably good enough:

```
Section1:
    SubsectionA: |
        regular expression
        regular expression
    SubsectionB: |
        regular expression
        regular expression
Section2:
    (etc.)
```

Your app will have to split the values of the subsections (which are simply strings with embedded newlines) into lines to retrieve the regular expressions. One thing that might be difficult would be expressions with leading or trailing blanks, but that applies to any format that allows unquoted values. An advantage of YAML here would be that you have sufficient quoting mechanisms to handle this.

Comment: Your elaboration on XML CDATA sections is confusing. They have nothing to do with elements named Section. Also spaces are not an issue, everything enclosed in a CDATA section is returned literally by the XML parser, including any whitespace.

Comment: If you want to use xml tags for structuring the configuration, you will need to name the tags somehow. A concrete example would be helpful for understanding.

Comment: YAML with the pipe format is a solid answer. [The YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) indeed calls this "literal style" and says _"There is no way to escape characters inside literal scalars."_.

Comment: You could still put them in a list, too, and use chomping to remove the trailing newline ([example](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-to-json/95bbb8))

Answer (score 10):

Consider [TOML](https://toml.io/en/v0.3.0)

It handles two different forms of raw strings:

```
regex    = '<\i\c*\s*>'
```

OR

```
regex2 = '''I [dw]on't need \d{2} apples'''
```

Comment: How do you store the regex `'''`?

Comment: @anion You could use: `'{3}`

Comment: you can't always replace `'''` to `'{3}` in any regex. for example `'''?` or `[''']`. Probably can always rewrite without it tho

Comment: @RiaD `'{2,3}` and simply `'` respectively

Comment: yes, I know how to do that in these specific cases. That's why I said "Probably can always rewrite without it"

Comment: @RiaD `'{2}'?` also works for your first one.

Answer (score 6):

[NestedText](https://nestedtext.org/en/stable/) is a configuration file format that makes a point of not requiring any escaping or quoting, which makes it very good for applications like this:

```
# regex examples from:
# https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417
Section1:
    SubsectionA:
        - (\W|^)stock\stips(\W|$)
        - (\W|^)stock\s{0,3}tips(\W|$)
    SubsectionB:
        - 192\.168\.1\.
        - 192\.168\.1\.\d{1,3}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know that there are any NestedText implementations available for .NET at the moment.  The reference implementation is for python3, so  you could make it work, but it'd probably involve launching an external python3 process.  Even if this isn't a useful suggestion for OP, though, I think that it could be useful for someone else with the same question.

Disclosure: I was involved in designing NestedText.

Comment: Cool! BTW to disclose the relevant info of your involvement, that's a _disclosure_. To disclaim responsibility, that's a _disclaimer_.

Answer (score 4):

### Roll your own

Seems a simple enough format; just write your own custom parser to deserialize from a plain text file (perhaps just like your first example) into your object model. This would require maybe a couple dozen lines of code.

You have a simple, domain-specific problem to solve; why saddle yourself with a bunch of generalized constraints and requirements to conform to some standard format? What benefit does it give you? You've already spent more time looking for an existing library than it would have taken to just write the code.

Comment: I used the second example from the OP (a subset of markdown), and wrote the code to parse it. But I'm not sure that's the most maintainable, the best design -- whether it would pass peer review or whether that was a "WTF?" design decision.

Comment: A "tab-delimited" format for example looks like it would be simpler to parse, maybe one compound LINQ expression, although perhaps not as easy to read and write.

Answer (score 3):

**Tab-separated value** format (.tsv) is a simple, easy to edit text format that allows any text within a field except TAB and newline characters.

There are no escaping rules in [its IANA format spec](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values).

TSV doesn't explicitly define a hierarchy of sections, but you can put section info in the first column with the regex in the second column. E.g. the first column could contain

```
Section1.SubsectionA
```

or to avoid repeating the section name,

```
Section1
.SubsectionA
```

So here's an example file:

```
section<TAB>regex1<TAB>regex2
Section1<TAB><TAB>
.SubsectionA<TAB>regular expression1<TAB>regular expression2
.SubsectionB<TAB>another regular expression1<TAB>another regular expression2
```

(`<TAB>` here stands in for a plain TAB character.)

**NOTE:** CSV reader libraries usually have configurable delimiters to support TSV format and other variations. Or just read text lines and split each line on `'\t'`.

I'm not familiar with .NET but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838365/how-to-read-tsv-file-using-asp-net

Comment: Very good! Thank you. It's perhaps not as human-readable (nicely formatted) as the two in the OP, but it is standard and much easier to write the code to parse it. And it does allow pairs of regular expressions (as required in the OP), i.e. a line can contain two regexps separated by a TAB -- because a simple regexp literal contains neither a newline nor a tab character.

Comment: @ChrisW yes! I added a second regex to each line in the example, and a note about using a CSV reader library and configuring the delimiter, or just splitting each line.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex syntax does not allow embedded whitespace, INI-files is your best bet, since a value can contain any non-whitespace character.

Any other format I can think of have some characters which have special meaning and therefore need to be escaped. For example, CData sections in XML is terminated by the `]]>` character sequence, but that sequence could be valid (if uncommon) in a regex and therefore needs escaping.

If the regex syntax allow embedded whitespace, I don't know of any mainstream format which can support this unescaped. Indeed, I wonder if it is even theoretically possible since basically any sequence of characters could occur in a regex.

Comment: **I wonder if it is even theoretically possible** A format where the regexp is delimited with arbitrary start and end character might suffice -- then you could just choose any delimiter that isn't already in the regexp.

Answer (score -1):

In configuration-files it is as far as i know nearly always required to escape some certain characters (`\n`, `'`,`"`, etc.). Because if you are not escaping it then the configurationfile-parser does not know where the regex ends. It is in every syntax always possible that the first character recognized after the regex should actually still be a part of the regex. And in general the end of a regex can be arbitrary characters, even characters which have a special meaning for your configurationfile-parser. Inside of files which contains other information you can probably not avoid that.

If you really do not want to escape anything then write your regex in a dedicated file without any other information than the regex and then in the configuration-file you can specify a file-path for the location of your regex-file. that's very unconventional but if there is a requirement that you really do not have to escape anything then you can do this as a design-decision.

Example:

```
Section1
    SubsectionA
        regexpA1.txt
        regexpA2.txt
    SubsectionB
        regexpB1.txt
        regexpB2.txt
```

Inside this `.txt`-files you do not have to escape anything but it is obviously not easy to read when someone opens your configuration-file.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion seems to me worse than the two in the OP -- it too is non-standard, and it's harder to read and parse. I think the two examples in the OP successfully store the regexps in the file without their needing any escaping. They're terminated by a newline.